# How to fire a javascript function after setting a radio button value with a mysql query result when the page loads

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm using php & mysql (with a pinch of javascript).  This is a simple "edit" form, that auto-fills the various elements from data in a table.  On the form is a set of radio buttons which are set by the data when the page loads.  As in the "add new" form, this "edit' form has javascript functions which are triggered by onclick(), which display either another set of radio buttons or a text entry box, when the user makes a selection. (That part works just fine.)

How can I trigger/fire these scripts to display the appropriate elements automatically when the page loads?  (Really don't want to delve into the jQuery arena at this time - as I need to get this piece of the project wrapped up ASAP.)

```
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align=right>Transport:&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "<td><input type=radio id=transppnd name=transp value='pnd'";
        //  $prepdel: var holding 1 or 0 from database table field
        if($prepdel>0){
          echo "checked";
        }
        echo" onclick='showpnd()'>Prep & Deliver";

        echo "&nbsp;<input type=radio id=transpcpu name=transp value='cpu'";
        //  $prepdel: var holding 1 or 0 from database table field
        if($prepdel<1){
            echo "checked";
        }
        echo " onclick='showcpu()'>Customer pickup</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: simplest: stick a `<script>startStuff();</script>` immediately before the closing `</body>`. or use `<body onload...>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to call your `showcpu()` and `showpnd()` methods on page load.  Just add a script like this at the bottom of your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    showpnd();
    showcpu();
</script>
</body>
```

I don't know php but maybe something like this?

```
if($prepdel>0){
    echo "<script type="text/javascript">showpnd();showcpu();</script>";
}
```

*****************************UPDATE********************************

```
echo "<input type=hidden id=porc name=porc value='$prepdel'>";

<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById("porc").value > 0)
    {
        showpnd();
        showcpu();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know php but you could write the above script tag if `$prepdel > 0` or whatever condition you want...

Comment: Hmmm... the showpnd and showcpu work fine for the onclick() events.. but how can I call or trigger a similar function based on the data returned  $prepdel?  Assign a hidden element like so:

echo "<input type=hidden id=porc name=porc value='$prepdel'>";

Comment: In theory this should work - however... I'm going to step away from it for the day, head for home and slowly consume a mark54812 chocolate coffee stout :) Thank you for you input thus far brso05!